Is is necessary to memorize the Vedic Samhita before studying the Upanishads and why?
Numerous smritis such as the Dharmasutras, Manusmriti and Yajnavalka Smriti instruct that children should be initiated at a young age and thereafter be taught to recite the Vedas. Moreover they don't restrict the right to study the Vedas merely to Brahmins but also extend it to Kshatriyas and Vaishyas (it's a separate question as to why Shudras are excluded).

"A Brahmin should be initiated in the spring, a Kshatriya in the
summer, and a Vaishya in the autumn; a Brahmin in the eighth year from
conception, a Kshatriya in the eleventh, and a Vaishya in the
twelfth." - Apasthamba Dharmasutra, 1.1.19 (translated by Patrick Olivelle)


"After he (a twice-born person) has undergone vedic initiation, he is
to be instructed in the observances and then taught the Veda in the
proper order and according to rule." - Manusmriti, 2.173

Needless to say this form of education is extremely rare in India today and restricted to a handful of Brahmin communities like the Namboothiri of Kerala and Vaidikis of Andhra and even among them it's declining as much of the younger generation is taking up white collar jobs and moving to the US and Europe.
Nevertheless from what I can gather, back when this was the primary form of education, it was expected that a child should have memorized the Samhita portion of at least one Veda (which would take 12 years) before moving on to the study of the Upanishads. Is that correct? and if so, why is it so necessary?
